# Не удаётся загрузить имдж на сайт

Tags: html, img

Начал работать в Laravel и решил сделать небольшой сайт. Но, прежде, т.к. уже сталкивался с подобным, решил проверить работоспособность файлов(изображений). В итоге, как бы я не писал путь, и абсолютный, и относительный, и завербованный и т.д., ничего не получается. Но заметил одну вещь. В инспекторе кода, на вкладке "сеть", у картинки статус - "заблокировано (другое)"
[image: Статус изображения]

Что это может быть, подскажите, пожалуйста. Я подумал на права доступа, но, вроде, в безопасности всем всё выдал, но картинке как было на меня пофиг, так и продолжается.
Может ли быть это из-за того, что я работаю именно в php-файле, в котором html? Бред, вроде, но а вдруг...
Абс. путь изображения - D:\SOFT\Education\game\resources\views\img\dipper.jpg.
На сайте, в коде элемента, он ищет её по: http:/127.0.0.1/resources/views/img/dipper.jpg (это если указать именно путь к файлу, т.к. папка img лежит на одном уровне с php-файлом.

Comment: Как минимум, изображения не должны лежать в `views`, для этого в `resources` или должна быть отдельная папка `img`, но тогда Вам нужно будет позаботиться о их копировании в папку `public`. Либо Вы ручками закините это в `public/img/`. В самом blade темплейте путь обычно указывается через хелпер [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-asset) `asset('img/dipper.jpg')`. Папка resources, предназначена для файлов, которые используются во время разработки и не должны быть напрямую доступны пользователям, потому и "заблокировано".

Comment: @Simon понял, спасибо большое за объяснение)